# cannot run android unit test if I set the shareduserId as "android.uid.system"

Tags: android, junit, uid

I got a problem when I was running a test that the target Package's sharedUserId is "android.uid.system"

when I type this in shell

```
    adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.lewa.security2.holder.ClearanceHolderTest     com.lewa.dunit.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

it never return a result.

but when I remove the "android.uid.system", it just works

can any one help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a unit test in android need to run after you kill the application.
but  applicaions with the shareduid `android.uid.system`  cannot be killed in this way.
so,you need to force close the application before run unit tests.